# SQL. How to check if record exists in Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, exists

I have a table "Table1" in database "TestDB". In the table there are 3 columns: id, name, description. So how can I check if record exists in Table1 ?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of why a simple `where` clause doesn't do what you want.

Comment: I want to check if there is an entry in the database before adding

Comment: Exactly! or Even lot more ways to find out. Post your query or more description

Answer (score 4):

Best way to check record is exist or not in sql server

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE ID = @ID )
BEGIN
END
```

Here we use **SELECT 1** because we dont want to load all column so it will use in performance.

Answer (score 2):

You use table columns like check record exists in Name or id

SQL Query is here.

```
Declare @id int=1
Declare @name='abc'

   IF EXISTS ( SELECT  id, name, description
                    FROM    Table1
                    WHERE   id= @id  or name=@name ) 
            BEGIN                    
                SET @RetVal = -1          --record  already exist          
                RETURN                    
            END
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXISTS`? Without further explanation, this is the best i can offer, however, if you actually expand your question, you'll get a far more comprehensive answer:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE Test (ID int);

SELECT 1 AS HasData
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test);
GO

INSERT INTO Test
VALUES(NULL); --intentionally NULL to show that even a single row
              --with the value NULL will cause EXISTS will return True

SELECT 1 AS HasData
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test);

GO

DROP TABLE test;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If exists (select * from table1 where Id = 2)
```

-- Do your stuff here.

Comment: For performance reasons, it is always a good idea to use a "select 1" instead of "select *" with an "If exists" because only a single instance is required to confirm the condition.